# Update a vector in a data.table

Tags: r, vector, data.table

I have this:

```
dt = data.table(index=c(1,2), items=list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5)))
#   index items
#1:     1 1,2,3
#2:     2   4,5
```

I want to change the `dt[index==2,items]` to `c(6,7)`.

I tried:

```
dt[index==2, items] = c(6,7)
dt[index==2, items := c(6,7)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One workaround is to use `ifelse`:

```
 dt[,items:=ifelse(index==2,list(c(6,7)),items)]

   index items
1:     1 1,2,3
2:     2   6,7
```

#### EDIT the correct answer:

```
 dt[index==2,items :=  list(list(c(6,7)))]
```

Indeed, you'll need one more list because data.table uses `list(.)` to look for values to assign to columns by reference.

---

There are two ways to use the `:=` operator in `data.table`:

1. The LHS := RHS form:

   ```
   DT[, c("col1", "col2", ..) := list(val1, val2, ...)]
   ```

   It takes a `list()` argument on the RHS. To add a list column, you'll need to wrap with another list (as illustrated above).
2. The functional form:

   ```
   DT[, `:=`(col1 = val1, ## some comments
             col2 = val2, ## some more comments
             ...)]
   ```

   It is especially useful to add some comments along with the assignment.

Comment: Why that works when this doesn't `dt[index==2,items:=list(c(6,7))]`?

Comment: @pomber I edit my answer with the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[index==2]$items[[1]] <- list(c(6,7))
dt
#    index items
# 1:     1 1,2,3
# 2:     2   6,7
```

The problem is that, the way you have it set up, `dt$items` is a list, not a vector, so you have to use list indexing (e.g., `dt$items[[1]]`). But AFAIK you can't update a list element by reference, so, e.g.,

```
dt[index==2,items[[1]]:=list(c(6,7))]
```

will not work.

BTW I also do not see the point of using data.tables for this.

Comment: This column is part of a bigger data.table, I'm using it mainly because of the binary search.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
dt$items[[which(dt$index==2)]] = c(6,7)
```